# Error using cout with pointer value

Tags: c++, pointers

I have problem in the following code:

```
int *ary = new int[2];
ary[0] = 1;
ary[1] = 2;

cout << &ary[0];   //no error
cout << &ary[0] + " " + &ary[1];  //error (expression must have integral or unscoped enum type  )
```

I cant understand why arise error using pointer value with string(integral)

Comment: What you are doing is adding unrelated pointers together, not creating strings. Perhaps you should [find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start from the beginning?

Comment: yes. I mix up with java. anyway thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cout` "streams" data into the standard output using the `<<` operator. Not the `+` operator.

```
cout << &ary[0] << " " << &ary[1];
```

The way you wrote it before attempted to add 2 `int*` with a `char[2]`, which aren't valid types to add with each other.

Comment: oops I have used java for a time. lol. that is my mistake. thanks.